# Trying to get previous and next object in template Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I need to get the previous & next value of the object (col2 from the object) in the same for loop iteration. Below is my index.html code:

```
    <script> 
                var i = 1;
                var j = 0;
 </script>


    {% for b in obj %}



        <tr>
            <td>{{ b.col1 }}</td>
            <td><span class="wrapped"><span>{{ obj.j.col2 }}</span></span> </td>
            <td id='myTable'></td>          
            <td id='myTable'></td>
            <td>{{ b.col5 }}</td>
            <td>{{ b.col6 }}</td>
            <td>{{ b.col7 }}</td>
        </tr>


<script>j=j+1;</script>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

views.py:

```
def display(request):

    return render_to_response('index.html', {'obj': my_model.objects.order_by('col2')})
```

What I tried was that when using: `{{ obj.0.col2 }}` or `{{ obj.1.col2 }}`, it displays the value of that cell correctly. However, when using `{{ obj.j.col2 }}`, it does not display anything. Why is this happening?? Why is it not reading j's value?? When I'm initializing `j` to `0` outside the loop and am incrementing value of `j` at the end of the loop as well!!

Comment: Your j variable is JavaScript not a template variable. Template variables are rendered on the backend before the page is loaded in the browser

Comment: The Django template language is by design very limited in it's functionality. If you need special information in your objects, preprocess the data in Python.

Comment: @KlausD. Okay but then why is obj.forloop.counter0.col2 also not working?? Is there a workaround that you could tell me. I just need a counter.